# Separate controllers resize related to each other and form size

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, user-interface

I want to design one simple form with Microsoft Visual Studio, I have one DataGridView and one ListView. When I resize the main form, I want the components to resize related to the size of main form and size of each other.

I use the anchor property but it didn't work as I expected, I want controllers to remain side by side in all situations.

As you can see in the 2 images below, when I maximize the window there is a gap between Datagridview and ListView. How can I fix this?

[image: Image showing the appropriate layout]
[image: Image showing the gap that appears as the window is resized]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Anchor of your grid to

```
//control to the left, this will expand and take most space
listview.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right

//control to the right, this will keep it's size 
grid.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right
```

Now if you want them to have always the same size;
add a `TableLayoutPanel` with 2 columns set to 50%, and add your `listview` and `grid` to it. (The `TableLayoutPanel`should be anchored so it expands)

Comment: I try that one but it didn't work, when you set all Acnhor for one controller one of them become bigger and if set both for two of them their size becoming strange

Comment: can you post how you have the anchors of each component?

Comment: do you want them both to grow, like being 50% of the size all the time?

Comment: If I set like the way you said the ListView fill the space and get bigger width than Grid. I said in the question I don't want this type.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA sorry that wasn't clear to me. See the edit, you should use the `TableLayoutPanel` control with 2 columns

Comment: If I set Anchor As you said I got :http://postimage.org/image/gill2s9tr/   and if set All 4 anchor for both of them I got  http://postimage.org/image/citi6vxw7/

Answer (score 0):

Add a panel put both controls in it. Get rid of teh panel borders if you don't like them.
Anchor all for corners of the panel
Choose one control and set it's dock style to left or right as appropriate, set the other one's dock style to fill.

If you want 50/50 split, then 
set anchors of left control to left, right panel to right. (and top and bottom for each.

Add a resize eventhandler to the panel.
Work out the widths of the two controls and set them.